# finding molar mass of a molecule

Tags: molecules, mole, mass-spectrometry

Why is the molar mass of a molecule defined as the the sum of molar mass of all the atoms present in the molecule?

For example, suppose we have to calculate the molar mass of $\ce{H_2O} $ molecule.

Then, $$\text{Molar mass of a } \ce{H_2O}\text{ molecule} = 2 \times \text{Molar mass of }\ce{H} + \text{Molar mass of }\ce{O}$$
= 2 * 1g/mol of H + 16g/mol of O

= ***2g/mol of H*** + 16g/mol of O

As you can see we get two contrasting results - "1g/mol of H" and "2g/mol of H atoms)

How can both "1g" and "2g" form 1 mole of Hydrogen?

I think that the confusion is with the use of units.
I have represented one mole of H like this = 18 g/**1 mole of H**
But when I multiply with 2 then also I get the same *denominator*,the result I get is 36 g/**1 mole of H**

Why am I getting the same denominator (1 mole of H) ?

I have one more question

Why $6.022 \times 10^{23}$ atoms of different elements (constituents of molecule) form $6.022 \times 10^{23}$ molecules of the substance?

Comment: make your question more elaborate and you're right ? what doubt do you have ?

Comment: My question is that how both 1 g and 2 g form 1 mole of H?

Comment: I am still not clear with your language . Although 1 mole of H atom would weigh about 1g .

Comment: In your units manipulation you're missing that it is 2 atoms of hydrogen per molecule of water.

Comment: @MaxW why is  the relative atomic mass of an atom numerically equal to it's gram atomic mass?

Comment: @user42209 because if you are counting atoms they are the same thing (barring terminology).

Answer (score 2):

Stoichiometry will decide how many moles of each element forms how many moles of the product. Hence, in your equation, 2 moles or 2x6.023x10^23 atoms of H will combine with 1 mole or 6.023x10^23 atoms of Oxygen to form 1 mole or 6.023x10^23 molecules of water. I hope this clears your confusion.

Comment: You can format mathematical and chemical expressions on Chemistry.SE using MathJax; [this post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86) contains further details.

Comment: @orthocresol thanks for letting me know! I was wondering how other people do the formatting here :)

Comment: No problem. There are a number of resources scattered on [meta], feel free to drop me a line if you need anything.

Comment: @MrityunjayGupta why is  the relative atomic mass of an atom numerically equal to it's gram atomic mass?

Answer (score 0):

The *mole* is simply a way of counting things, but you have to be careful what you are counting. *Molar mass* is just a way of counting the mass of one mole of something.

If you are counting *atoms* then 3 moles of atoms (two moles of hydrogen *atoms* and one of oxygen *atoms*) come together to make one mole of water *molecules*. Moles are not additive because they count *different* things on the two sides of the equation (atoms on one side, molecules on the other). But mass is additive so the total *mass* of one mole of water is the sum of the masses of the three moles of its components. So the molar mass of water is about 18g/mole.

The molar counts (and masses) depend on what we are counting. If we count hydrogen and oxygen *molecules* then there would be 1 mole of hydrogen molecules (H2) and half a mole of oxygen molecules. The one mole of water would still weight the same if we count and weigh correctly.

Comment: why is  the relative atomic mass of an atom numerically equal to it's gram atomic mass?